# Difficulty parsing RSS feed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa

I'm trying to parse an RSS feed (http://www.themostunrealbeats.com/?feed=rss2) using `NSXMLParser`. I am having difficulty finding the picture in the article. Here is where the picture is in the RSS feed.

```
<media:content url="http://themostunrealbeats.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/madeon.png?w=400" medium="image">
    <media:title type="html">madeon</media:title>
</media:content>
```

Specifically, I want `http://themostunrealbeats.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/madeon.png`. Yet in the delegate method for `NSXMLParser`, I don't find anything.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"media:content"]) {

        NSLog(@"%@", string);
        [content appendString:string];

    }

}
```

`string` has no value. How can I parse this?

Comment: Parsing XML generally seems painful; perhaps you could use an RSS library instead of manually parsing it?  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8005597/291280) recommends [RSSKit](http://github.com/H2CO3/RSSKit).

Comment: @Isaac I'll look at that. Do you know how to build the framework so I can use it in my project?

Comment: I haven't looked too closely but it looks like you might be able to build the framework by running `make` from the command line in the source directory.  Personally, I'd probably just directly include the source in my project and use `#import "[...].h"` to import the specific class headers needed (since `RSSKit.h` uses `#import <RSSKit/[...].h>`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// NSXMLParser has a following method
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

// In this method parameter 'attributeDict' will return you all the sub attributes of main attribute.
// In your case its 'url' of Picture.

// I hope this will help you. Check this out.
```

Comment: Great! The RSS feed is also returning `&#8220;` instead of quotes, and  does the same thing for other characters. How should I deal with that?

Comment: show me your URL response. so i can understand more. if you are getting NSData in response. then you need to encode it.        NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: I'm doing this: `parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.themostunrealbeats.com/?feed=rss2];` I would assume a string is returned.

Comment: Jack Try this NSLog(@"%@",[@"&#8220;This is my String&#8220;" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#8220;" withString:@""]);